# Virtual cam on a virtual machine (or elsewhere) seen as a cam in the physical machine

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, vmware, camera

I'm using a software that blocks every software like OBS, Cyberlink YouCam, Chrome Remote Desktop, Team Viewer, etcetera, and it cannot be execute on a virtual machines because it detects them.
I'd like to use a virtual cam; to do so is it possible to cheat the physical machine so that it can see a virtual cam on a virtual machine as a real cam?
I'm using VMware.

In the case the virtual machine was not ok to do the above, is it possible to upload a video somewhere and create an online virtual cam that can be used on the physical machine?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148665/discussion-on-question-by-gennaro-arguzzi-virtual-cam-on-a-virtual-machine-or-e); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.